# trying to use set variable from predefined variables and use it in condition for stage in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to setup variable from predefined variable of pipeline resources and use it in condition for stage, but i could not succeeded. below is the my pipeline

```yaml
     resources:
     pipelines:
     - pipeline: pipeline1
       project: appcom
       source: pipeline-api
       trigger: 
         branches:
         - develop
         - feat/*
     - pipeline: pipeline2
       project: appcom
       source: pipeline2-api
       trigger:
         branches:
         - develop
         - feat/*
    
variables:
- name: alias
  value: $(resources.triggeringAlias)

stages:
- stage: DEV
displayName: Deploying to DEV
jobs:
- deployment: Deployment
displayName: Deploying to Dev
environment: dev
pool:
name: 'CDaaSLinux'
strategy:
runOnce:
deploy:
steps:
- template: /variables/variable.yaml
    - script: echo $(alias)

    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          if [ "$(alias)" == "pipeline1" ]; then
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=apiname]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1.pipelineName)"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=branchName]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1.sourceBranch)"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1.sourceCommit) | cut -c -7"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=helmpath]P02565Mallorca/pipeline1-api"
          elif [ "$(alias)" = "pipeline2" ]; then
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=apiname]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline2.pipelineName)"
             echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=branchName]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline2.sourceBranch)"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline2.sourceCommit) | cut -c -7"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=helmpath]P02565Mallorca/pipeline2-api"
          fi

    - script: echo $(dockertag)
    - script: echo $(helmpath)
    - script: echo $(apiname)
    - script: echo $(branchName)
```

but I would like to execute above task on top of all stage and set them as global variables and use those variable in condition on following stages.

needed condition would be as below

```yaml
stages:
- stage: DockerBuildtask
condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables['$(branchName'], 'refs/heads/develop'), eq(variables['$(branchName'], 'refs/heads/release'), eq(variables['$(branchName'], 'refs/heads/feat*.'), eq(variables['$(branchName'], 'refs/heads/bugfix*.')))
```

below is the variable.yaml content

```
steps:
- task: Bash@3
inputs:
targetType: 'inline'
script: |
if [ "$(alias)" == "pipeline1" ]; then
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=apibuild]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1.pipelineName)"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=branchName;isOutput=true]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1.sourceBranch)"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]$(echo '$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1.sourceCommit)' | cut -c -7)"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=apiname]pipeline1-api"
```

could someone help me on this issue. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> trying to use set variable from predefined variables and use it in condition for stage in azure devops pipeline

You could use Output variables from previous stages:

```
Dependencies.stageName.outputs['jobName.stepName.variableName']
```

Please check the document [Jobs can access output variables from previous stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#jobs-can-access-output-variables-from-previous-stages) for some more details.

And we need also add a property `;isOutput=true` and `name` to the previous stages：

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=branchName;isOutput=true]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1.sourceBranch)"


- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Inline Powershell'
  inputs:
    TargetType: inline
    Script: |
      if ("$(alias)" -eq "PipelineA")
      {
       ...
      }
    pwsh: true
  name: powershelltest
```

Then we could use the `Dependencies.stageName.outputs['jobName.stepName.variableName']` as condition in next stage:

```
- stage: DockerBuildtask
  and(succeeded(), or(eq(dependencies.ScanImage.outputs['ScanImage.powershelltest.branchName'], 'refs/heads/develop'), eq(dependencies.ScanImage.outputs['ScanImage.powershelltest.branchName'], 'refs/heads/release'), eq(dependencies.ScanImage.outputs['ScanImage.powershelltest.branchName'], 'refs/heads/feat*.'), eq(dependencies.ScanImage.outputs['ScanImage.powershelltest.branchName'], 'refs/heads/bugfix*.')))
```

**Note:** Since you need add the condition **on top of all stage**, we need update the stages refer from **`stageDependencies.stageName.jobName.outputs['stepName.variableName']`** To **`Dependencies.stageName.outputs['jobName.stepName.variableName']`**

**Update2:**

> here i am setting variable(variable.yaml) under deployment not job. so
> how would i frame below one
> Dependencies.stageNam.outputs['jobName.stepName.variableName'] should
> i meniton Deployment as jobName ??

The answer is yes.

You could use the **`Dependencies.stageName.outputs['jobName.jobName.stepName.variableName']`** as condition.

Note: There are two `jobName` in the conditions.

Comment: Hi Leo, i am setting up the variable under deployment in stage not on job.
- stage: DEV_DCR
displayName: Deploying to DEV-DCR
jobs:
- deployment: Deployment
displayName: Deploying to Dev-Dcr
environment: P02565-dev
pool:
name: 'CDaaSLinux'
strategy:
runOnce:
deploy:
steps:
- template: /variables/variable.yaml

need to use these variabls on following stages. then how should i mention on
Dependencies.stageName.outputs['jobName.stepName.variableName'] as job name

Comment: @pranathi, would you please update this comment in your question, hard to read in the comment?

Comment: updated question.. here i am setting variable(variable.yaml) under deployment not job. so how would i frame below one
Dependencies.stageNam.outputs['jobName.stepName.variableName']
should i meniton Deployment as jobName ??

Comment: @pranathi, You said you set variable(variable.yaml) under deployment not job, I saw it, but your question now is that you want to use these variables in variable.yaml in the next stage? Or do you just want to use branchName in the next stage? If so, it has nothing to do with the variable in variable.yaml you set?

Comment: i need to use only branchName which is a part of variable.yaml

Comment: @pranathi, OK, would you please share your  `variable.yaml` in your question? Does it mean that your Bash@3 task is in `variable.yaml`?

Comment: @pranathi, I appreciate all your work, But I am currently in another thread, I will check if there is a solution later, thank you for your patience.

Comment: @pranathi, As I test, you could use `Dependencies.stageName.outputs['jobName.jobName.stepName.variableName']` as condition, check my update2 answer for some more details.

Comment: thanks, the problem i see is value for variable branchName is not setting , it says null during condition validation.   any idea based on above configurations

Comment: Finally it works.. Many Many thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Hi  Leo Liu-MSFT,  is it possible to tag pipeline with $(alias). so we can have filter releases per api ?

Comment: or is it possible to name pipeline with something like this 
name: $(alias)